# Can't get response from ASP.NET web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api

I'm setting up an ASP.net web API, but I keep getting 404 from all Http routes.

This is running on http://localhost:52011/ since that is the default location that VS2013 uses. I've added a simple test `HttpRoute` that just returns a string if it's called with a GET to test connectivity.

Directory browsing is enabled for feedback that the web API is in fact on localhost, and all directories of the project are visible.

I've tried setting the controller name fixed in the routes in WebApiConfig.cs and read a lot about the `HttpRoute` mappings, but I keep getting either a 404 or a:

> "No Type was found that matches the controller named *controllername*".

I'm using Postman to test since that was recommended and easy to use.

Any tips are welcome!

WebApiConfig.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace BadgePrinter
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {            
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            //route to print badge.
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "apiPrint",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{Bedrijf}/{Aanspreektitel}/{Voornaam}/{Achternaam}/{Jobtitle}/{Kopies}/{Rijksregisternummer}/{BadgeAfdruk}/{printer}/{Image}",
                defaults: new { Image = RouteParameter.Optional}
            );
            //test route to get string back
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "apiTest",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

BadgeController.cs (the only controller in the project)

The first method is the one I'm going to have to use eventually, but the testmethod is the one I use for testing.

```cs
using BadgePrinter.CardTemplates;
using BadgePrinter.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace BadgePrinter.Controllers
{
    public class BadgeController : ApiController
    {     
        //removed the first method since it was big and distracting.
        // test method
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAllProducts()
        {
            return Ok("some product");
        }
    }
}
```

Link for the testmethod that I'm using:
http://localhost:52011/api/BadgeController/Products/1

I also tried this link, even though that shouldn't matter:
http://localhost:52011/api/BadgeController/Products/1

Result:

```json
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:52011/api/BadgeController/Products/1'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'BadgeController.cs'."
}
```

For the other `HttpRoute`, I keep getting 404, but I'll be in heaven if I can get the test to work :)

PS: I'm new to this kind of thing (ASP.net and API's) so I'm sorry if I'm being an idiot.

Comment: `http://localhost:52011/api/BadgeController/Products/1` - as far as I can see you don't have any GET method which would map to an ID parameter. Your GET method doesn't accept any inputs. This is quite likely to be why you get a "Not Found" response - there's no action method which matches the pattern of the URL. Have you tried just `http://localhost:52011/api/BadgeController/Products/`? Also you generally don't write "Controller" explicitly in the URL. The MS Web API tutorial explains that, if memory serves. So in fact just `http://localhost:52011/api/Badge/Products/` should be right I think.

Comment: And with `/Badge/` instead of `/BadgeController/` ?

Comment: The posted code for `GET GetAllProducts` will not automagically match `GET Products/id`. PrintBadge is totally unrelated, remove it from the question, it just distracts.

Comment: " i also tried changing the HttpRoute defaults to defaults: new { controller = "Badge" } " that won't matter since you already specify the controller in the URL. You just need to make it "badge" instead of "badgecontroller" as per standard documented Web API conventions. Have you tried the URL I mentioned, yet?

Comment: Actually looking again, I'm not even sure where you're getting the "Products" part from? Try just `http://localhost:52011/api/Badge/` as a GET

Comment: Thank you guys so much! After changing the action so that it accepted an integer as input and using this(http://localhost:52011/api/Badge/GetAllProducts/1) URI i got the string back. @ADyson i was indeed using Products even though that wasn't a name of an action. I will remove the portion of PrintBadge because it's of no value to the question i asked. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues here:

1) Your controller name `BadgeController` but in your API it should be `Badge` only. The correct URL should be:

```
http://localhost:52011/api/Badge/xxx
```

2) I can't see method name `Products` or something like that in your code.

3) If it is a `POST` method, it must have `[FromBody]` in parameter input.

Comment: thanks! http://localhost:52011/api/Badge/GetAllProducts/1 worked for me after changing the action so that it accepted an integer.

Comment: @SebastianDB if you want to rename the API method, you can do it by this way:

`[HttpPost("TheNameYouWant")]`

`[HttpGet("TheNameYouWant")]`

And the URL will be like this: `http://localhost:52011/api/Badge/TheNameYouWant`

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your URL:

```
http://localhost:52011/api/BadgeController/Products/1
```

As far as I can see you don't have any GET method which would map to an ID parameter. All you have in your controller is

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetAllProducts()
```

which doesn't accept any inputs.

2) The documented Web API convention is that you don't write "Controller" explicitly in the URL. Just the first part which is unique to the controller (`Badge`) in this case is required.

3) I can't see where you are getting the "Products" part of the URL from. There's no custom route definition or attribute which would make that part of the route. Again the convention is that you define an action method whose name starts with "Get" and that will map to a `GET` request to the controller name, with no further bits and pieces on the end. The rest of the method's name is irrelevant - and in your case `AllProducts` doesn't match to `/Products` anyway...so even if that was necessary it would still be incorrect.

In conclusion, the correct URL to access your GET action should be:

```
http://localhost:52011/api/Badge/
```

---

N.B. If you were to either change your existing GetAllProducts method, or add a second method like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
  return Ok("Product" + id);
}
```

Then you could use the ID in your URL, e.g.

```
http://localhost:52011/api/Badge/1
```

and it should route to this method.

Answer (score -1):

Try dropping the controller part of the url:

http://localhost:52011/api/Badge/Products/1

Comment: there's no action method which accepts the `1` as input. The only GET method available does not accept any parameters. So the routing engine will not be able to map this URL to an action method, even after the controller-name part of the URL is fixed. If you have been reading the existing comments you might have already seen this mentioned.

Comment: @ADyson exactly, i changed the action so that it accepted an integer and then used http://localhost:52011/api/Badge/GetAllProducts/1 and it worked! thanks everyone!

Comment: @ADyson - you're correct, however the comments weren't there when I started writing.